# Change color of hline by group: ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `facet_grid` plot with 2 `geom_hline`s per plot.  I'd like to color each of those lines separately.  I thought if I added this color to the `geom_hline` dataframe I could supply the color inside of `aes`.  This colors by group but uses the default ggplot colors.

Here's the code:

```
p <- qplot(mpg, factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), nrow(mtcars), T)), 
           data=mtcars, facets = vs ~ am)

hline.data <- data.frame(z = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d")), 
    vs = c(0,0,1,1), am = c(0,1,0,1))

hline.data <- transform(hline.data, z0 = as.numeric(z))
hline.data <- rbind.data.frame(hline.data, hline.data)
hline.data[5:8, 1] <- c("b", "c", "d", "a")
hline.data[5:8, 4] <- c(2, 3, 4, 1)
hline.data[, "col"] <- rep(c("red", "black"), each=4)

p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = z0, colour=col), hline.data)
```

How can I get the "red" and black `geom_hlines` I am expecting?

[image]

Comment: Um....`scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","black"))`? :) Remember, this isn't base graphics!

Comment: Oh my gosh this is a duh moment, I've been away from ggplot2 too long.  Will you post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the scale values:

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("black","red"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are specifying the exact values in the data (`hline.data`), you want to use the identity scale:

```
+ scale_colour_identity()
```

Comment: This seems to be the most explicit +1 Thank you.